# Answer marked as accepted lost after a merge

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, moderators, merged-questions, moderator-intervention

**EDIT:** The issue raised in this question was quickly solved by SO moderators.

Take a look at this two questions that where asked with a few hours of difference between each other:

1. [What to use now that FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken() is deprecated.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51125169/5050924)
2. [FirebaseInstanceIdService is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51123197/5050924)

Objectively, they are two different questions. The first one questions the use of a deprecated method and the second one questions the use of a deprecated class that is not even mentioned on the first question.

I answered the first one. It was marked as accepted and quickly started receiving up-votes as Firebase hasn't updated its documentation and there should be many users looking for this answer. The code I use in the answer  was a result of logic reasoning reading [getInstanceId](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId#getInstanceId()) documentation and my experience using Task objects. I did not copied, nor ever used nor tested the code I posted, but it took the user out of the problem and was marked as accepted.

After 3 days I stopped receiving votes, what seemed strange to me and got back into the question: it was marked as duplicate in favor of the second question I wasn't aware of. What got my attention is that it was marked as duplicate by a user that answered the second question and that edited his answer to include the code I used in the first question.

I felt quite disappointed as it was wrongly and doubtfully marked as duplicate so I flagged the first question for moderator's intervention briefly explaining the situation and suggesting if possible to be rollback the duplicate mark.

At this point, despite feeling injured, I was willing to wait for the moderator's feedback until today that I received a notification linking to the second question with reputation loss because of a merge. Now not only I've been damaged because of a doubtfully **marked as duplicate**, my answer is appearing in a different question that is not the one I've originally answered, looking out of context because it doesn't answers the second question and it wouldn't be of any surprise if it starts getting some down-votes because of not being a correct answer, looking as if I didn't understand the question.

I know moderators do have a long queue of flags and don't have the time go deep in trying to understand the content of posts when they can come out with an issue they do not know about. That's why they put their trust on other high reputation user's suggestion.

The objective of this post is not to get into the discussion whether the questions are duplicate or not. The issue I want to point out now is that the answer I posted, that helped the user who asked the question and that was marked as accepted, is now hanging on a post as a wrong answer for a question I've never intended to answer.

I only can think of the possibility of executing one of the following actions:

1. Edit the answer to fit the second question trying at least to look as if I understood the question and really tried to post a correct answer to it.
2. Wait the feedback of my flag for moderator's intervention and leave the answer as it is taking the risk of affecting my reputation.
3. Flag the first question again but this time issuing the merge.
4. Deleting the answer that is now on the second question.

Is there any other possibility? What should I do?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

So... I made a mess here. I apologize for that.

When reading your flag, I really only had two options:

1. Decline the flag
2. Merge the questions

Flags asking us to re-open a question will largely be met with a decline. This is something the community can and should handle.

However, your flag also mentioned that the closer had edited your answer into theirs - which would make the closure an abuse of the gold badge. That didn't appear to be the case - as they edited their answer on the 2nd of July and closed the question on the 4th.

Due to the fact that both questions were asked at nearly the same time, and yours was the first answer to address the `getToken` depreciation, I decided to try to make everyone happy and merge your answer into the target so that it maintains its visibility.

That... clearly, didn't work out as I'd hoped. So again, I'm sorry.

This was originally going to end with a 'Sorry, but merges are permanent', but turns out [Shog9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9)'s able to fix just about anything. The merge has been reversed.

Comment: It was a hard flag to handle, as the person who closed it as a dupe also copied code from the OPs answer, so there were several issues to be addressed.

Comment: Guys, thank you very much for your intervention and feedback. I wasn't expecting for you to act like this and so quickly. I was really looking for suggestions from the community.

Comment: I suspect Shog9 has a brain chip implant with constant remote root access to the Stack Exchange DBs

Comment: If you see a black cat run past twice, you know @Shog9 has been fixing something.

Comment: Yeah, gold badge abuse, I wonder in this case, can you actually flag the gold badge abuser who copied your code, flagged your answer as duplicate, as being rude? If yes, do the moderators take the time to reprimand the guy? or just leave it like that?

Comment: @Mr.J Flagging that behaviour as rude will most likely result in a declined flag, as what you're flagging isn't immediately obvious. Unless the behaviour you're flagging matches the text of the flag, you should use a custom flag and be as specific as possible.

Comment: @Rob Thank you for your answer, but another question, out of curiosity, does that case even deserves a flag? Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Mr.J Both abusing a gold badge and plagiarism are cases worth flagging for, yes. Do note though, that simply disagreeing with their closure isn't enough to flag for - that should be handled by the community.